# Keep rectangles in screen in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a `pygame` and I want to create a screen with random "players". I define the players by `getplayer`.
Everything works fine except that in every frame a new player is created but the former players are away. I know why my code does this but I don't know what to do so that the players are kept.
My code is the following:

```
import random
import pygame

pygame.init()

HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 800

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

def getplayer():
    randr = random.randrange(256)
    randg = random.randrange(256)
    randb = random.randrange(256)
    xpos = random.randrange(WIDTH)
    ypos = random.randrange(HEIGHT)
    pwidth = random.uniform(WIDTH/100, WIDTH/10)
    pheight = random.uniform(HEIGHT/100, HEIGHT/10)
    pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, (randr, randg, randb), (xpos, ypos, pwidth, pheight)) 


running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    clock.tick(1)
    SCREEN.fill((200, 200, 200))

    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    getplayer()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to change player to a class object (if you don't know what those are: they are really useful and you should definitely take the time to learn about them https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/python/object-oriented-programming/classes-and-objects-i/tutorial/).

Each player object can then be tracked using a list.

```
import random
import pygame

pygame.init()

HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 800

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))


# It's easier to keep track of all your values using a class object
class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.randr = random.randrange(256)
        self.randg = random.randrange(256)
        self.randb = random.randrange(256)
        self.xpos = random.randrange(WIDTH)
        self.ypos = random.randrange(HEIGHT)
        self.pwidth = random.uniform(WIDTH/100, WIDTH/10)
        self.pheight = random.uniform(HEIGHT/100, HEIGHT/10)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, (self.randr, self.randg, self.randb), (self.xpos, self.ypos, self.pwidth, self.pheight)) 


running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# Used to keep track of all your player objects
lst_players = []

while running:
    clock.tick(1)
    SCREEN.fill((200, 200, 200))

    # Create a new player
    player = Player()
    # Add the player to your list
    lst_players.append(player)
    # Draw all of your players
    for player in lst_players:
        player.draw()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Might want to put a limit on the number of `Player` instances created because it current unlimited and the will quickly be millions...

Comment: @martineau you're absolutely right, but I think that would only make the answer more cluttery and harder to understand

Comment: Sorry, I disagree. Adding an `if` statement to the display loop and doesn't seem that complicated, IMO.

Comment: @martineau but it adds information that could be perceived as an answer to the question while it's only an improvement on the code

Comment: Thank you very much, that's great and I know a bit about classes. But I get the following error: `def draw_player(self):
                          ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`. In the class the function's name is `draw_player` and later it's `draw`?

Comment: Just fyi, I've made an example project, it could be useful for figuring out how and what exactly: https://gitlab.com/nathan_vanthof/space_invaders/blob/master/core/entity.py

Comment: @TobiSonne I've coded it all in stackoverflow, pretty sure I've missed a space somewhere

Comment: @TobiSonne fixed it for you

Comment: @Rabbid76 I've got to go, but feel free to do so, I agree it would be better than creating a new rectangle object every time

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now with correct spaces and `def __init__(self):` instead of `def __init__():`

Comment: Also `player.draw()` should be `player.draw_player()`